# Does 'timer' take more CPU power?

Tags: c#, timer, cpu-usage

I've used timer and I found it very helpful while taking decisions in seconds or milliseconds.
Now I have strong feelings that continuous running of timer gradually increases consumption of processor cycles.

I've created an application (C#) and used 'timer tick' to execute 'three' instructions per 1000 milliseconds (1 sec) and I noticed that after 5 minutes application was consuming 5% of CPU power and 10% after 10 minutes.

If this progress remains constant then what will happen after 4-5 hours if I run my application in background?

Should I avoid excessive use of timer?

```
private void currentTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
   label2.Text = dt.AddSeconds(i).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
   i++;
}
```

Comment: I don't think, I is related to use of the timer. There must be something in **your** code

Comment: Are you sure it is the timer and not other code? Perhaps references that are not cleaned up or objects holding more and more data?

Comment: If you could show us your code, we could analyze what's going on.  There's three kinds of timers, and they all behave a little differently :-) that and whatever you do in your event handler can make a lot of difference.

Comment: You could describe what you're doing a bit more.

Comment: This is the event's code:


private void currentTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
                label2.Text = dt.AddSeconds(i).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                i++;
 }

Comment: This is not the code responsible for your CPU use.

Comment: @ebb Using a threading timer wouldn't work. I assume he's using the winforms timer.

Comment: I agree with @CodeInChaos. The callback method has nothing to do with your CPU use. This is how the the Timer object works: The thread pool has a single thread for all Timers, which will wake up when the next Timer should call it's callback. The thread then calls `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => timerCallback)`, which calls the callback method for the Timer object which time is up.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, My comment was not an answer, but simple just some basic theory, to understand that if his using `System.Threading.Timer`, it's not the class that's messing it up - but him.

Comment: I didn't enable the timer at all and the CPU usage was constant at '00'.

Comment: @MuhammadAliDildar, What `Timer` class are you using?

Comment: What is your timer's `Interval` property set to?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that not the timer itself is the cause, but whatever instructions are called by it. Do you create objects in those instructions of yours, or call something that runs in a separate thread? Starting threads or allocating resources, and forgetting to close them can certainly lead to the behavior you described.

Comment: In first two instructions I am changing 'text(s)' of two 'labels' and third instruction increments a 'double' value.

Comment: Unless some of those labels have some onChanged() or similar events active, the problem should not be in this part of the code. Did you try isolating the problem? What happens when you comment out everything inside your "timer tick"? What happens if you set the timer interval to 10 times slower, or don't start it at all?